# Custom font doesn't work in interface builder!

Tags: iphone, fonts, interface-builder

I've downloaded a font that's called "aldo the apache (.tff) " from dafont.com.

I used it with different programms like adobe illustrator and it seemed to work just fine.

Recently i tried to use it in a game that i'm making to experement. It didn't work -_-.

IB was displaying the font as a slightly bigger version of arial.

How can i solve this problem and get the font to display correctly?

If you have any suggestions, please post them down below.

-DD

Answer (score 4):

You have to edit your `<appname>-Info.plist` file and create a new [UIAppFonts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3) key with type array, where each element is a String with the name of your font file, in this case `AldotheApache.ttf`. Then use the name in IB or with UIFont as it shows in the application Font Book app of your Mac, in your case `Aldo the Apache`. Obviously the font should also be added as a resource of your project.

Comment: tnx, i got one more question: How do i create the key thingy? Im in the plist and have 4 options to choose from...

Comment: Select the file. Go to the right pane and select any element. Press +. Type UIAppFonts and press enter. Expand the element. Go to Item 0 and type the name of the font in the colum Value.

Comment: ok now... i get the first part about the info plist. BUt what should i do next?

Comment: Once the plist part is ok, you can go to IB and change the font for the element that shows the text. For example, drop a UILabel to your GUI and look for the property where you change the font of that UILabel and select your font (you have to install the font using Font Book in OS X for the font to be available). Then run the application and see if the font shows too in the simulator.

Comment: What can we do even after all if it doesnt work, via code I'm able to set font